# Any feedback on the lib Ajax-Cross-Domain and the Jquery patch?

Tags: ajax, cross-domain

I am looking for a way to get non JSON data from a foreign domain using Ajax.

We found

- http://www.ajax-cross-domain.com/ lib and
- http://dev.jquery.com/ticket/3342 Jquery patch.

Has anyone tried these?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to do cross-domain communication in javascript, you can probably do better than the old links above. There are newer, easier-to-use approaches including [EasyXDM](http://easyxdm.net/) which are worth trying.

Comment: Thanks for your recent 'evangelism'! For some reason the project has been hard to 'sell'..

Comment: You're welcome!  XDM is really doing the right approach to XDM, where you hide browser differences but always choose the "best" mechanism for a particular browser. This is what JQuery does for DOM maniupuation and it's great to see this happening for XDM too.  BTW, it might be nice to see a JQuery plugin variant of EasyXDM-- you'll probably find a lot of enthusiasm for the EasyXDM approach within the JQuery community.

Comment: I'm not really a big fan of jQuery, and I fail to see how making it a plugin would make it easier to use :) Unfortunately, people in the 'jQuery community' seems to believe that if it *doesn't* have a jQuery plugin then its crap (when in most cases its exactly the opposite).

But hey, its a better suggestion than the one someone gave me about 'using jQuery for attaching events instead of doing it myself' :)

Comment: I second the jQuery plugin suggestion. I am considering doing it myself. The reason this would make it easier to use EasyXDM is because I could then use jQuery's built-in ajax functions, but rely on EasyXDM to do XDM.